# ASP.NET Form Input - Width unexpected behavior (not expanding 100%)

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4, width

Just a simple form:

- **Problem**: `<input>` width is not expanding to 100%
- I believe the width of the element is set to 100% if the class `form-control` is set to it

[Screen shot: Output from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeQZL.png)

- Using Visual Studio 2017 (MVC5 ASP.NET C#) - same code used as below
- Both `<input>` and `<textarea>` is fixed to some width. I don't know why !! Even tried to explicitly provide `style="width:100%"` but doesn't work
- **Works perfectly** when i try to run the same code in (https://jsfiddle.net/Dhinesh_Ram/0yh4Lx7w/) or "W3 school's Tryit Editor" but not it Visual Studio
- Browsers i tried to debug : Chrome, IE, Edge

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/3/lumen/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="well bs-component">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Feedback</legend>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
          <span class="help-block">Try to eloborate if its a Bug report, a screenshot would be helpful</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?
I have the same problems...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Go to your Project Map and open the folder:
"Content"

Then you search for "site.css"

then you have something like this:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

now change max-width to 100%

```
max-width: 100%;
```